# Messed up sed syntactics in hadoop startup script after reinstalling JVM

Tags: hadoop, sed, jvm

i'm trying to run 3 node Hadoop cluster on Windows Azure cloud. I've gone through configuration, and test launch. Everything look fine, however, as i used to use OpedJDK which is not recommended as VM for Hadoop according to what i read, i decide to replace it with Oracle Server JVM. Removed old installation of java with Yum, along with all java folders in /usr/lib, installed most recent version of Oracle JVM, updated PATH and JAVA_HOME variables; however, now on launch i getting following masseges:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-Bit: Name or service not known
HotSpot(TM): ssh: Could not resolve hostname HotSpot(TM): Name or service not known
Server: ssh: Could not resolve hostname Server: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname VM: Name or service not known
```

e.t.c. (in total about 20-30 strings with words which should not have anything in common with hostnames)

For me it looks like it's trying to pass part of code as Hostname because of incorrect usage of sed in start up script:

```
        if [ "$HADOOP_SLAVE_NAMES" != '' ] ; then
  SLAVE_NAMES=$HADOOP_SLAVE_NAMES
else
  SLAVE_FILE=${HADOOP_SLAVES:-${HADOOP_CONF_DIR}/slaves}
  SLAVE_NAMES=$(cat "$SLAVE_FILE" | sed  's/#.*$//;/^$/d')
fi

# start the daemons
for slave in $SLAVE_NAMES ; do
 ssh $HADOOP_SSH_OPTS $slave $"${@// /\\ }" \
   2>&1 | sed "s/^/$slave: /" &
 if [ "$HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP" != "" ]; then
   sleep $HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP
 fi
done
```

Which looks unchanged, so the question is: how change of JVM could affect sed? And how can i fix it?

Comment: `unknown option to 's'` indicates you have too many slashes. Does one of your `$slave` values contain a slash?

Comment: `$(cat "$SLAVE_FILE" | sed  's/#.*$//;/^$/d')` sigh...

Comment: That would be ok. But the error might happen here: `sed "s/^/$slave: /" `

Comment: Which version of Hadoop are you running?

Comment: @ChrisWhite 2.2.0 GA is where i saw this error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So i found an answer to this question: My guess was wrong, and everything with sed is fine. Problem however was in how Oracle JVM works with external libraries compare to OpenJDK. It did throw exception where script was not expecting it, and it ruin whole sed input.
You can fix it by adding following system variables: 
**HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR** which should point to **/lib/native** folder of your Hadoop installation and add **-Djava.library.path=/opt/hadoop/lib** to whatever options you already have in **HADOOP_OPTS** variable (notice that /opt/hadoop is my installation folder, you might need to change it in order for stuff to work properly). 
I personally add export commands to hadoop-env.sh script, but adding it to .bash file or start-all.sh should work as well.

Comment: Thanks alot for following up on your own question and providing such a detailed answer!

Comment: I'm also having another problem while configuring hadoop 2.x, and would appreciate it if you could take a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943766/hadoop-unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library-for-your-platform-error-on-centos

Comment: For me, the sed error occured when I used `java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`. It got fixed when I replaced it with `Oracle jdk1.8.0`.